# Creation of a raster dataset from polylines

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, rasterization, raster-conversion

I face an issue with the Raster tool. I have Polylines that I want to convert to Raster. The spatial reference coordinate system is World Mercator (WGS 84).

I used the "Convert Polyline to Raster" tool. But the problem is that I expected to get an attribute table with all the cells (I defined the cell size as 1000) with values corresponding to the ID of the line crossing the cell... However, I get an attribute table with all values greater than zero and therefore not all the cells.

Is this was linked to the Coordinate System, and if so, do I need to re-define the project and use a system like Lambert Conic (Projection System)?

[image]

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Could you add to the question, perhaps expand on what you were expecting as the output? Just a table or a raster of 1s and 0s? What are you trying to accomplish? Do you need to work solely with Raster data?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. I am using ArcGis. 

As output I am expecting a raster of 1s and 0s. I actually need to build a measure for a research project and the Raster data appeared to be the best method.

Comment: Try creating a fishnet for the extent of the line layer. Set your raster cell size as the fishnet grid size. Then select by location and assign a value of 1 to the grids that are selected. Convert the fishnet to raster using polygon to raster tool. That should give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's actually what I tried to do, but the problem is that I keep getting the Error 001018: the number of output features exceeds OID limits, etc. I don't understand why. Basically what I did is projecting the initial WGS 84 polyline to Lambert Conic and then try to get a fishnet 50 by 50

Comment: @Rororo that error pops up when the number of features you working with has more than 2mil rows / features. Bascially its telling you the grid size you chose is too large. Try playing around with the settings of the fishnet, how big is the study area? You could create a buffer around the line and use that as the fishnet extent template if you need 50m x 50m...that being said, if your study area is 100s of km then a 50mx 50m grid will yield a lot of fishnet cells. You may then need to look at a full raster approach.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.